# How can I chart the average number of events per user?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a scenario that I would like to chart on Google Analytics.

**Scenario:**

We have an event with an Event Category called `video_played`. 
I would like to analyze how many videos the average user played.

How can this be achieved via Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main options.

A) You can set up Video_Played as a goal. This would give you a conversion rate for the Video_Played event.

B) Set up a Google Sheet with the Google Analytics add on. With this create two reports, one with the total users during the period, and one with the total events during the period. Create a third sheet for workings, and then calculate the specific 'event rate' for the event of interest.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on

Comment: This is good. In general, are events mostly useful just for the purposes of creating goals? It seems the ability to analyze events by themselves is pretty limited, from within the Analytics platform itself.

Comment: 1) Events are useful for measuring interactions.

Comment: 1) Events are useful for measuring interactions. By default Google Analytics only knows where a user is, not what a user is doing. This is the main purpose of events.   2) Google Analytics is limited as an analysis tool. Its primary use is the capture and reporting of weblog data. This is why there are other tools such as Klipfollio, Google Sheet, R, Python, which can all be set up with API access to further analyze the data and report on it in the way that suites the user.